# how to find how many times a line crosses a curve?

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

Given $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}-4x+1$, for what $m$ values the equaition $f(x)=m$ has:

(1): 1 solution

(2): 2 solutions

(3): 3 solutions

Can this question be solved without sketching a graph? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in calculating the cubic discriminant for
$$
\frac{1}{3}x^2 - 4x + (1 - m) = 0
$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Comment: You could check whether $\frac13x^3 - 4x + (1-m)$ has a non-constant factor in common with its derivative. The Euclidean algorithm may be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=x^3-12x+3-3m\Rightarrow  f'(x)=3x^2-12=0 \rightarrow x=\pm 2$$
$$f''(2)=12, f''(-2)=-12.$$ Then
$$f_{max}=f(-2)=19-3m, f_{min}=-13-3m$$
(1) Three distinct root if: $f_{max}>0$ and $f_{min} <0 \Rightarrow -13/3 <m <19/3.$

(2) Two distinct roots if $m= 19/3, -13/3$

(3) Other wise only one real root.

Comment: Jsut trying to learn...Assuming we are dealing with $y=mx$ intersections with the curve, when $m$ is undefined, the line is vertical, there could be only 1 point of intersection between the curve and the line. In The range $m\in (-\infty, -2.7]$ there is 1 intersection and when $m\in(-2.7,2.6)$ there are 2 intersections. When $m>-2.7$ there are 3 intersections. This comment has no exact number and is not comprehensive though. Please refer to the plot here:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ukgm0kbnw9

Comment: @NoChance  Actually in a polynomial equation it is  the last coefficient (independent of x) matters most. Your who;e equation is $x^3/3-4x+(1-m)=0$ its roots are where it cuts x-axis. Seeing intersection of $ y=x^3/-4x-1$ and $y=mx$ as rootsfor the former equation is another way. But the former is better.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess this question is rather difficult for me, I will take some time to study it.